# Having an error connecting to my SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

The user is looking at a list `LibraryFragment` and clicks one of the options (`Item1` or `Item2`), from there I wanted to show another list (`GFragment`) that is created dynamically from the items received from the database.  In the logCat I get this error:

```java
08-30 13:56:54.087: E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(22622): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/j.j.l.library.v11/databases/library_dev.db", &handle, 1, NULL) failed

Failed to open the database. Closing it.
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with the code or why it is doing this?

---

The code I am using for the database is:

```java
public class DatabaseHelper {

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/j.j.l.library.v11/databases/";    
private static String DB_NAME = "library_dev.db";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

public DatabaseHelper(){
}

//Open the database.
public void openDatabase() throws SQLException{

    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}   

//Return the columns we want.
public List<String> getQueryColumn(String tableName, String[] columns){

    Cursor cursor;
    List<String> info = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor = myDataBase.query(tableName, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        info.add(cursor.getString(0));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return info;
}    

//Close the Database.
public void closeDatabase() throws SQLException{

    myDataBase.close();
}

}
```

Another List I am trying to create dynamically from the database:

```java
public class GFragment extends ListFragment {

private DatabaseHelper gList;
public static final String GROLE = "role";
public static final String[] ROLENAME = {"name"};


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    gList = new DatabaseHelper();
    gList.openDatabase();

    List<String> values = gList.getQueryColumn(GROLE, ROLENAME);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values));
    gList.closeDatabase();

}
}
```

This is the list the user is looking at right before there is a call to retrieve the dynamic list from the database:

```java
public class LibraryFragment extends ListFragment{

String[] libraryList = {"Item1", "Item2"};  

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, libraryList));
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    //Get the position the user clicked.
    Fragment newFragment = null;
    String listPosition = libraryList[position];

    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);

    if(listPosition.equals("Item1")){
        newFragment = new GFragment();                      
    }else if (listPosition.equals("Item2")){
        newFragment = new ITFragment();
    }

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.myFragments, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    transaction.commit();

}

}
```

Comment: Check path to your db.Or try to create empty db in your app and then import data from your db.

Comment: Yahor10 could you supply code on how to do this or have a site I could go to that shows how to import data from the db please.

Comment: To import your db - you should copy db file into your application/database folder.But if you want to create a new empty db read about SqliteOpenHelper class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you don't create this database `library_dev.db`, so it's empty, resulting in a `NULL` reference; a closing operation is taken afterward.

You need to handle the `creation/upgrade/remove` of the database in a class which should extends from `SQLiteOpenHelper` first. Then use this class to get your database:

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { // blah...database create/upgrade handling }

MyDatabaseHelper myHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(yourContext);
SQLiteDatabase myDatabase = myHelper.getReadableDatabase(); // now you can use `myDatabase` freely
```

You can refer to a proper guideline for this at: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: So if i made a separate class: public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { // blah...database create/upgrade handling } in my onCreate() and onUpgrade() I would leave these blank inside right? Cause I am not creating a database from scratch so I wouldnt have to use db.execSQL(), right?

Comment: you must implement `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()`, if you don't intend to create an empty DB then implement the code to copy your database from `/assets` to your specified path. This `SQLiteOpenHelper` class is the start of all further database interaction onward, implement what you want to do here.